# Using Scrapy Files Pipeline to download (PDF) documents within a range of years

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am trying to download pdf forms from: https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html

I want to download all PDF files available within a range of years (ex. 2018-2020).
The downloaded PDFs should go into a directory with the name of the form, and the file name should be the "Form Name - Year"(ex: Form W-2/Form W-2 - 2020.pdf).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I can't download the files.

** pdf.py **

```js
import scrapy

class PdfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pdfSpider'
    start_urls = [
          'https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('.LeftCellSpacer').xpath('@href').extract():
            url = response.url
            path = response.css('a::text').extract()
            next_link = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_link, callback=self.parse_det, meta={'url': url, 'path': path})

    def parse_det(self, response):

        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()

        yield {
            'path':response.meta['path'],
            'file_urls': [extract_with_css('a::attr(href)')],
            'url':response.meta['url']
        }


from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},
    'FILES_STORE': '.',
})
c.crawl(PdfSpider)
```

** settings.py **

```js
BOT_NAME = 'taxform_scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['taxform_scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'taxform_scraper.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'taxform_scraper.pipelines.TaxformScraperPipeline': 300,
   'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1
}

MEDIA_ALLOW_REDIRECTS = True
```

When I run the scrapy command `scrapy runspider pdf.py` I get the below terminal output

** Terminal Output **

```js
2021-02-03 19:40:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2021-02-03 19:40:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 24 2020, 16:23:16) - [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020), cryptography 3.3.1, Platform macOS-11.1-x86_64-i386-64bit
2021-02-03 19:40:29 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-02-03 19:40:29 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
2021-02-03 19:40:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 6b9b91bc6d1b537e
2021-02-03 19:40:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: taxform_scraper)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 24 2020, 16:23:16) - [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020), cryptography 3.3.1, Platform macOS-11.1-x86_64-i386-64bit
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 24 2020, 16:23:16) - [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020), cryptography 3.3.1, Platform macOS-11.1-x86_64-i386-64bit
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 77210fa8243f5811
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'taxform_scraper',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'taxform_scraper.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['taxform_scraper.spiders']}
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3666830b830f31d0
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['taxform_scraper.pipelines.TaxformScraperPipeline']
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6025
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html> (referer: None)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html> (referer: None)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.irs.gov/404> from <GET https://apps.irs.gov/robots.txt>
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 232,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 4264,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.467604,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 4, 2, 40, 30, 521028),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 19,
 'memusage/max': 51257344,
 'memusage/startup': 51257344,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 4, 2, 40, 30, 53424)}
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 232,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 4264,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.483096,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 4, 2, 40, 30, 522640),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 35,
 'memusage/max': 51032064,
 'memusage/startup': 51032064,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 4, 2, 40, 30, 39544)}
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.irs.gov/404> (referer: None)
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 2 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 4 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 5 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 7 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 9 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 10 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 11 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 15 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 16 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 17 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 18 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 19 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 20 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 25 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 26 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 28 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 29 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 46 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 63 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 64 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 69 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 92 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 128 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 142 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 259 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 289 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 403 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 649 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 679 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 700 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 718 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 832 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 994 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1020 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1150 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1166 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1180 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1210 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1240 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1243 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1246 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1249 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1252 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1255 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1258 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1261 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1273 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1276 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1279 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1296 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1302 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1308 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1314 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1320 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1326 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1334 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1357 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1390 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1392 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1395 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2021-02-03 19:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html> (referer: None)
2021-02-03 19:40:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-02-03 19:40:31 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1299,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 24872,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.986045,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 4, 2, 40, 31, 54803),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 65,
 'log_count/INFO': 16,
 'memusage/max': 51466240,
 'memusage/startup': 51466240,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 4, 2, 40, 30, 68758)}
2021-02-03 19:40:31 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I have tried many solutions on Stackoverflow, but nothing is working. What am i doing wrong? How can I download the files within a year range?

Answer (score 1):

try this, its work fine

```
import scrapy

class PdfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pdfSpider'
    start_urls = [
          'https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url
        for link in response.css('table.picklist-dataTable'):
            links = link.css('td.LeftCellSpacer > a::attr("href")').extract()
            for pdfurl in links:
                yield scrapy.Request(pdfurl, callback=self.download_pdf, meta={'url': url, 'path': pdfurl})

    def download_pdf(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        self.logger.info('Saving PDF %s', path)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: This worked. however the files are not in a **separate folder** with the name of the file. I only got 27 files. Do you know how I would extract them in **year range from 2018-2020**

Comment: You need to set path to download pdf file in separate folder. if '2017' or '2020' in response.url then download other wise pass, try it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still not sure how to do that!